# BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to migrate an ASP.Net MVC application from Windows Server 2012R2 server to a Windows Server 2019 server. I copied the application folder to the new server's inetpub/wwwroot and created an application with the appropriate App Pool in IIS. The application works for the most part except when the code uses SQLServer.Types. This is the error:

BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods

I installed the .Net Framework versions used by the app.
The App Pool have the exact same setting in the new server as the 2012 one.
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll is in the app's bin folder.